# How can I include my direct x install location in clion?

Tags: c++, clion, directx-9

I'm trying to use clion, however when I try to include d3dx9.h it says it cant find the file specified, meaning that I'd have to include my directory for my dx9 install. I know in vs you can do it in your project properties, but I cant figure out how to do it in clion. Any help would be greatly appreciated, thank you.

Comment: Maybe you can have CMake find it for you and add the appropriate include path. This script may help: [https://github.com/Microsoft/DirectXShaderCompiler/blob/master/cmake/modules/FindD3D12.cmake](https://github.com/Microsoft/DirectXShaderCompiler/blob/master/cmake/modules/FindD3D12.cmake)

Comment: @drescherjm I know where it is, just not what code I should use to specify it for clion to use

Comment: My point was CMake does not know where it is. You can leverage CMake scripts to solve the problem in CLion (which uses CMake). With that said if you only compile on 1 system and don't distribute your code to anyone you may not want the extra effort to have CMake find it for you

Comment: The ``FindD3D12.cmake`` is designed for the Windows 10 SDK which includes Direct3D 12 and Direct3D 11. There are also the basic legacy Direct3D 9, DirectSound, and DirectInput headers & libs in the Windows SDK. ``D3DX9.H`` is for the D3DX utility library (D3DX9, D3DX10, and D3DX11 are all deprecated) which were only in the end-of-life DirectX SDK. See [Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/directx-sdk--august-2009-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create *CMakeLists.txt* file in root of your sources, even if you build your project using different build system. CLion by default uses *cmake* and does not understand configuration files of other build systems and it needs this *CMakeLists.txt* to set up indexing of your project.

In this *CMakeLists.txt* configure paths to libraries either by *find_package* (for some standard includes like *Boost*) or by *include_directories*.

Example:

```
project(MyProject)
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11)
set(CMAKE_CXX_EXTENSIONS OFF)

find_package(Boost)

include_directories(
    /opt/openssl10/include/
    /path/to/dx9/include/
)
```